# How do i push same object value in to an array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I've been trying to deal with the json below for a few days.

```
[
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", user_id: "admin", type: "click", query: "spider"},
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", user_id: "admin", type: "search", query: "spider"},
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:38", user_id: "user", type: "click", query: "hi"},
]
```

If a certain value is duplicate, I want to add it to a new array. like this

```
[
  {
    createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", 
    user_id: "admin",
    query: "spider",
    type: "click",
    result: [
     {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", user_id: "admin", type: "search", query: "spider"}
    ]
  },
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:38", user_id: "user", type: "click", query: "hi"}
]
```

The groupBy function of lodash is the most similar, but I am not familiar with JavaScript. 
anyone can help me how to handling those json?

Comment: How would you consider two values are duplicated? Is there any criteria?

Comment: I think date and user_id, query can be duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is another approach.

1. uses one `Array.reduce` to build one dictionary to store how many times the key occurs and where to save the data of the key.
2. uses another `Array.reduce` to loop all elements then apply your logic.

```js
const data = [
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", user_id: "admin", type: "click", query: "spider"},
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37", user_id: "admin", type: "search", query: "spider"},
  {createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:38", user_id: "user", type: "click", query: "hi"},
]

function relayout() {
  const indexes = data.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    pre[`${cur.createdAt}-${cur.user_id}`] = [0, 0] // count, position in result array
    return pre
  }, {})
  return data.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    const key = `${cur.createdAt}-${cur.user_id}`
    if (indexes[key][0] > 0) {
      pre[indexes[key][1]].result = [
        ...(pre[indexes[key][1]].result || []),
        cur
      ]
    } else {
      pre.push(cur)
      indexes[key][1] = pre.length - 1
    }
    indexes[key][0] += 1
    return pre
  }, [])
}

console.log(relayout(data))
```

Comment: I need to learn how to use reduce . It was a good answer for me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37",
    user_id: "admin",
    type: "click",
    query: "spider",
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:37",
    user_id: "admin",
    type: "search",
    query: "spider",
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2021-09-09 07:38",
    user_id: "user",
    type: "click",
    query: "hi",
  },
];

let map = new Map();

arr.forEach((obj) => {
  const { user_id, createdAt } = obj;
  if (map.has(`${user_id}|${createdAt}`))
    map.get(`${user_id}|${createdAt}`).push(obj);
  else map.set(`${user_id}|${createdAt}`, [obj]);
});

const result = [];
for (let [, v] of map) {
  const [first, ...rest] = v;
  const temp = Object.assign({}, first);
  if (rest.length) temp.result = rest;
  result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```